# nix-shell default.nix: How to install rPackages.data_table with the zlib dependency?

Tags: dependencies, nixos, r, nix

I have a multi-user installation of nix on ubuntu 22.04. I'm trying to develop an R package that depends on `data.table`, but am unable to install `data.table` with `zlib` headers so that I can use the `fwrite` function with gzip compression.

Here is the `default.nix` I'm using with `direnv`:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

let
    rlibs = with rPackages; [
      R
      Rcpp
      data_table
      roxygen2
      pkgbuild
    ];

    _libs = with pkgs; [
        zlib
        ccls
    ];

in mkShell {
    nativeBuildInputs = [
      rlibs
      _libs
    ];
}
```

Everything installs fine and runs, but when I call

`fwrite(iris, "iris.txt.gz', compress="gzip")` I get

`Compression in fwrite uses zlib library. Its header files were not found at the time data.table was compiled. To enable fwrite compression, please reinstall data.table and study the output for further guidance.`

At first I didn't have `zlib` in `default.nix` so I added it and tried reinstalling. This required cleaning out the full set of packages. I can do `nix-store --delete`, but it also makes me garbage collect all the specified packages. Reinstaling did not solve the problem though. I don't see any output to inspect either.

How do I specify `zlib` as a dependency? Also is there a way to re-install a package with nix? I can't find any documentation online about it - any results are about reinstalling nix as a whole, not a single package.

UPDATE:
I've also tried

`nix-shell -p pkg-config zlib R rPackages.data_table`.

During the `data.table` install, there are messages that pkg-config was not found. However, in that shell, running `pkg-config --libs zlib` gives

`-L/nix/store/37a5krk4a1a8vhl93q2bm9nbv8hymyii-zlib-1.2.13/lib -lz`

Trying the nix manuals override doesn't work either:

```
{
    packageOverrides = super: let self = super.pkgs; in
    {

        rEnv = super.rWrapper.override {
            packages = with self.rPackages; [
                data_table
                ];
        };
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, when using an interpreter only the packages declared as part of that interpreter are available. In case of R this can be achieved with [an `rWrapper` override](https://nixos.org/manual/nixpkgs/stable/#r).

Comment: That example is for adding R and packages to the user profile: would an override work in a default.nix file as well? I tried this and added zlib as well, but data.table compilation could not find the headers. I get a message during data.table installation that `pkg-config` could not be found. This was true even when I used `nix-shell -p pkg-config zlib` before installing that override.

Comment: Can you show what you tried?

Comment: `nix-shell -p pkg-config zlib R rPackages.data_table`:
* installing *source* package 'data.table' ...

file 'configure' has the wrong MD5 checksum

** using staged installation

*** pkg-config is not installed.

... - The rest of the logs are of data.table being compiled with the -DNOZLIB flag

Comment: That's not using `rWrapper` or an override though…

Comment: I couldn't put the full derivation in the comment, but it was the same errors when I used the override example with data.table as one of the packages.

Comment: I also tried the default.nix example for R with zlib as a build input, but no luck.

Comment: I can't really help if you can't show the code.

Comment: Didn't think to use an edit: I've added the example override above.